# How I can be notified when a batch file ran within java ends?

Tags: java, batch-file

I executed a batch file from within my Java code like below:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start update.bat");`

I want to know whether can I get any notification when this batch script completes. Is it possible?

Regards,

Anand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a reference to the Process and waitFor the process to stop, this will halt your excecution.

```
 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start update.bat");
 int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

Do as the good example in this [link (When Runtime.exec() won't)](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4). If you read the whole article you will avoid and understand many pitfalls of the exec command.

Then you can read up on `ProcessBuilder` which is a more modern way to invoke other processes.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know  , with code samples .

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default Java ProcessBuilder.

```
  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "update.bat");
  builder.start();
  builder.waitFor();
```

The call to `waitFor` will block, so you once it returns you know your batch script is done.

Alternatively, you can use the commons-exec jar. This has more options for checking the result and doesn't block your thread. See [this example](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html) on how it works.